# Is there an option for user to virtually sign a waiver?

Tags: cognito-forms

Wondering if there's an option for user to virtually sign a waiver on this form.

Answer (score 1):

We are adding [e-signature support](https://trello.com/c/iDqwRjjR) to [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) in a release in the next two weeks.  This will allow users to "sign" a form with their mouse, pen or finger on both PC's and mobile devices.

Currently you can simply require users to click a checkbox and/or enter their email address as an alternative to confirm their acceptance of the form.  We are adding e-signature as a more concrete way of "signing" a form.

These signatures will automatically be included in PDF's generated by Cognito Forms.  We are also adding support for [custom Word document templates](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy) for merging, which will support including e-signatures as well.

Comment: This feature was released on September 14th.